# SWATCH - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: log-files, ftp

What I want/need/desire is to log when a user logs into my FTP server.

Problem: I can't make swatch work the way I should be able to.

This data is logged to a file - but of course these logs are not kept very long.  I can't keep the logs around forever, but I can extract data from then, analyze it, store results elsewhere.

If there is a better way to do this than the following, I'm all ears.

Swatch version 3.2.3

Perl 5.12

FTP: VSFTP

OS (Test): OS X 10.6.8

OS (Production): Solaris

From man I see I can pass contents to a command .. so I should be able to echo those values to file, do a sed/cut/uniq thing on them for stats.

```
$ man swatch
(snip)
exec command
       Execute command. The command may contain variables which 
       are substituted with    fields from the matched line. A $N 
       will be replaced by the Nth field in
       the line. A $0 or $* will be replaced by the entire line.
```

Swatch file .swatchrc

```
watchfor /OK LOGIN/
 echo=red    
 pipe "echo "0: $0 1:$1 2:$2 3:$3 4:$4 5:$5" >> /Users/bdunbar/dev/ftplog/output.txt"
```

Launch with

```
$ swatch -c /Users/bdunbar/.swatchrc --script-dir /Users/bdunbar/dev/ftplog -t /Users/bdunbar/dev/ftplog/vsftpd.log &
```

Test

```
echo "Mon July  9 03:11:07 2012 [pid 14938] [aetech] OK LOGIN: Client "206.209.255.227"" >>  vsftpd.log
```

Results - it's echoing to TTY.  This is not needed or desired on the server, but it does tell me things are working.

```
ftplog  
*** swatch version 3.2.3 (pid:25780) started at Mon Jul  9 15:23:33 CDT 2012

Mon July  9 03:11:07 2012 [pid 14938] [aetech] OK LOGIN: Client 206.209.255.227
```

Results - bad!  I appear to not be sending the variables to text.

```
$ tail -f output.txt
0: /Users/bdunbar/dev/ftplog/.swatch_script.25780 1: 2: 3: 4: 5:
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer: **man page is wrong.**

Variable for 'entire line' is $_

So this will echo the entire line to terminal.

```
#.swatchrc
watchfor /OK LOGIN/
      exec echo $_
```

One could also send this to email, or in my case to a file for further analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I know this may be late, but i had the same problem and found the reason.
You must use capturing groups in the regular expression (that's what the numbers refer to).

Example:

```
/OK LOGIN: Client (.*)/
```

`$1` will represent the client IP address in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You are quoting the `exec` part of the man page but you are using actually the `pipe` command.

```
pipe command[,keep_open] 
    Pipe matched lines into command. Use the keep_open option to force
    the pipe to stay open until a different pipe action is run or until 
    swatch exits.
```

So change the `pipe` to `exec` and by my understanding it should work.

Comment: So I was.  I've switched it around - same result.  My problem seems to be that $0 is not, as claimed in man, the entire line but the shell being executed.